# HTTP Status 500 - No Token available. twiiter4j 4.0.3

Tags: java, twitter

I am trying to integrate twitter login in my dummy web App . But while getting OAuthAccessToken , it says

**HTTP Status 500 - No Token available.**

Here is my code for creating twitter instance

```
twitterConfigurationBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
        twitterConfigurationBuilder.setDebugEnabled(true)
                .setOAuthConsumerKey(oAuthConsumerKey)
                .setOAuthConsumerSecret(oAuthConsumerSecret);
twitterInstance = (new TwitterFactory(
                twitterConfigurationBuilder.build())).getInstance();
```

Here How I am redirecting for Authentication :

```
RequestToken requestToken = twitterInstance
                    .getOAuthRequestToken(callBackURL);
            req.getSession().setAttribute("requestToken", requestToken);
            resp.sendRedirect(requestToken.getAuthenticationURL());
```

Here How I am getting OAuthAccessTken

```
RequestToken token = (RequestToken) req.getSession().getAttribute(
                "requestToken");
        String verifier = req.getParameter("oauth_verifier");
        req.getSession().removeAttribute("requestToken");
        try {
            // Exception Occurred here
            twitterInstance.getOAuthAccessToken(token, verifier);
        } catch (TwitterException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Here is the stackTrace :

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No Token available.
    twitter4j.auth.OAuthAuthorization.ensureTokenIsAvailable(OAuthAuthorization.java:71)
    twitter4j.auth.OAuthAuthorization.getOAuthAccessToken(OAuthAuthorization.java:131)
    twitter4j.auth.OAuthAuthorization.getOAuthAccessToken(OAuthAuthorization.java:146)
    twitter4j.TwitterBaseImpl.getOAuthAccessToken(TwitterBaseImpl.java:362)
    com.xxx.social.controller.Twitter.doGet(Twitter.java:67)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

**P.S.
 I tried twitter4j 4.0.3 and 4.0.4 and included core,stream api in pom**

Comment: Check that you don't have some null `RequestToken`.

Comment: `getOAuthAccessToken` is called with a null token, so start tracking backwards from there. Maybe it's null already when it's set.

Comment: Thank you both of you .I got it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RequestToken is **null** at

```
RequestToken token = (RequestToken) req.getSession().getAttribute(
                "requestToken");
```